# Request blocking

Tags: laravel, apache, dns

I have an issue on my website.
When I accessed the website by IP everything is good but when I access the website by domain name I got this error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at `<URL>` was loaded over HTTPS, but
requested an insecure stylesheet `<URL>`.  This request has been
blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
https://141.105.67.4/en/games
https://g11games.com/en/games
```

Can you please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you website is being loaded via `https`, but the scripts contained within the website, are being loaded via `http`. Likely, in your config, you have set `APP_URL` to point the `http` URL, so all assets on your website are using that as the base URL. Changing that to HTTPS should resolve the errors.

Answer (score 0):

fixed by adding

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```